# ssh -L (error: bind: Address already in use)

Tags: networking, ssh, port-forwarding

Pretty simple, I know that this has happened to me before. Couldn't find a good answer on AU.

I was running an ssh session with ports bound:

```
ssh -L 3000:<server_name>:22
```

I just lost my connection. When I try to reconnect using the same command, I get the following error:

```
bind: Address already in use
channel_setup_fwd_listener: cannot listen to port: 3000
```

How do I reset ssh on my machine to allow the port to be bound again? Resetting the local machine works.

Comment: Related question: [linux - Python \[Errno 98\] Address already in use - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4465959/python-errno-98-address-already-in-use)

Answer (score 118, accepted):

Couldn't you just kill whatever is using that port?

```
 lsof -ti:5901 | xargs kill -9
```

`lsof -ti:5901` to find whatever is using port `5901`.

Pass the whole thing to `kill -9` to kill whatever was using port `5901`.

Replace with the port you want to open up again.

Comment: Yes, you could change the port number to whatever port is being blocked. I am going to mark this as the answer.

Comment: If you are cautious and/or forgetful like me, you may wish to run lsof on its own and find out what the process is before killing it. `lsof -ti:5901` will return a process number, which you then pass to `kill -9`

Comment: what if nothing is using port 5901 (or whatever local port you are specifying)?

Comment: Try `sudo` if the process isn't coming up with `lsof`

Comment: I see no processes even with `sudo`.

Comment: There is no reason to `kill -9` unless the program is _completely_ unresponsive. Killing a process with signal #9 (SIGKILL) terminates it immediately without giving the process a chance to flush buffers, close filehandles and sockets, remove temporary files, etc., all of which the process _can_ do if you use `kill` (defaults to SIGTERM), followed by `kill -1` (SIGHUP; hangup) and `kill -2` (SIGINT; what Ctrl+C sends) if that doesn't work, and finally `kill -9` **if nothing else works**.

Comment: indeed kill -9 could cause unexpected exit of processes

Answer (score 13):

I suppose you have still something connected to local port 3000.

You can find it with

```
netstat -tulpn | grep 3000
```

and then dispose of it. For example in my machine:

```
[:~] % netstat -tulpn | grep 5900
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5900            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2547/vino-server
tcp6       0      0 :::5900                 :::*                    LISTEN      2547/vino-server
```

correctly identifies the process waiting and connected on port 5900 (vnc server).

Another useful command is

```
fuser 3000/tcp
```

...all of them may need to be run with `sudo` if you do not own the process which is opening the port.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will have to dig into it to see if I can recreate the issue. The only possible application that could have been listening on port 3000 was the old ssh session that was disconnected. My user owned the process, so I assumed I would be able to run a `killall ssh` and have it die. Guess that's not the case

Comment: Thanks for the reminder to use `sudo` - that's what I was missing.

Answer (score 7):

I was able to recreate and fix it by doing the following:

- Open up something that will list your processes (`ps -ae`)
- Kill the process called `sh` (`kill <proc_number>`)

Then reopen the ssh connection

Alternatively, I have had success with:

```
killall ssh
```

In the terminal on the local machine

Answer (score 2):

one more contender: `ss`

it can be used like this: `ss -ltp | grep 3000` to find the program listening on port 3000

Answer (score 1):

Just linking this answer here as it worked for me as a permanent solution for this issue. I was using multi-hop SSH bindings to connect to Postgres, MySql and MongoDB databases for e.g.:

```
ssh -L 5432:localhost:5432 -L 27017:localhost:27017 -L 3306:localhost:3306 user-name@first-hop-ip -p [ssh-port] -t ssh -L 5432:localhost:5432 -L 27017:localhost:27017 -L 3306:localhost:3306 user-name@second-hop-ip -p [ssh-port]
```

And the first hop was keeping the bindings active even when SSH was diconnected due to being idle.

**The solution text taken from below original answer:**

> You have to use ClientAliveInterval in your sshd_config.

```
ClientAliveInterval 15
```

**The cause:**
When we do not explicitely exit the connection to the SSH, say by Ctrl+C or `exit` command but it is closed due to a network issue or being idle for long, the first SSH hop/server keeps the binding active even if ssh disconnected. This solution keeps checking for an active SSH Client and closes the active binding when disconnected. If the ssh client is not active after above setting's specified period x 3 (default value) retries(ClientAliveCountMax)

**Link to permanent solution: https://superuser.com/a/742109/1898055**